# Cloudflare rule: strip trailing slash

Tags: cloudflare

I'm able to remove trailing slashes by having two redirect rules:

- **No** query string: `https://foo.com/*/` -> `https://foo.com/$1`
- **Yes** query string: `https://foo.com/*/?*` -> `https://foo.com/$1?$2`

But I'd prefer to do this with one rule.

I tried:

- **No/Yes** query string: `https://foo.com/*/\??*` -> `https://foo.com/$1$2`

But I can't seem to get it working.
Any ideas on something else to try?